# How to retrieve all Groups from LDAP with Perl

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

I have a Perl script wich binds to an LDAP server and retrieves all users. So far it works good but I want to filter that search in order to gather all groups. Once I have all groups the user can select one of these groups and I'll show him only users that are member of that group. How can I do those queries? I tryed this one:

```
my $mesg = $ldap->search(
    base => $base,
    filter => '(objectclass=user)',
    attrs => ['memberOf']
);
```

But then some groups are repeated and I will have to manually filter the result (and I'd like to avoid that). And what about the second query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cnThe filter to get all groups is "`(objectclass=group)`" you can retreive groups in only one organizationalUnit (scope => 'one') or in all suborganization (scope => 'sub')

```
$mesg = $ldap->search(  filter=>"(&(objectclass=group)(cn=the group choosen by the user)", 
                        base=>"ou=Monou,dc=societe,dc=fr"
                        scope=>"sub"
                        attrs=> ['cn', 'member']);
@entries = $mesg->entries;
foreach $entry (@entries)
{
    $entry->dump;
    @member = $entry->get_value("member");  # returns all members 
}
```

For more help see [An Introduction to perl-ldap](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7086?page=0,1)

---

Edited

So the filter you were looking for is :

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=Mongroupe,OU=MonOU,DC=societe,DC=fr))
```

Comment: First query works fine (I retrieved all groups) but I can't find a way to select users from a given group, there is no member attribute. I tryed a query with *objectclass=user* and *memberOf=group chosen* but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Gor a given group, the member attribute contains the Distinguish Name of the members.

Comment: Got it! With your query I managed to retrieve all members of a given group, only problem is that now I only have the CN of users when instead I want all their attributes. Is there a way to filter that with objectclass=user?

Comment: Two solutions. 1) You only need the common name, and you've got it parsing the DN with text cn=x. 2) For each member you can build an LDAP search with the filter "(distinguishedName=dn)"

Comment: I can't do it in this way for technical reasons. My Perl script is producing a DSML XML file with all users as result. If I have to retrieve informations user by user then I'll have to modify a lot of code wich I have already written. I mean I can do that it's not a big deal BUT if I can retrieve users (and their attributes) filtred by a chosen group with a single query that would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use such a filter : "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=Mongroupe,OU=MonOU,DC=societe,DC=fr))"

Comment: Worked like a charm! I knew it I had to do it this way just I did some mistakes while trying and I thought it was wrong. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use objectclass=* to get all.

```
my $msg = $ldap->search(base => $dn,
            scope => 'one',
            filter => "(objectclass=*)");
$msg->all_entries;
```

Comment: Nice! And what about my second question? How can I select all users from a chosen group?

Comment: Uhm.. this search does not return groups, is returing something else but I don't understand it. Are you sure scope and filter are correct?

Comment: The filter here is returning objects of every class.  You'd want a more specific filter.  For example, `&(objectCategory=Group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)` would not only just get groups, but it would get you only Security Groups, not Distribution Lists, in AD anyway.