# Perl LDAP search for user being a CN attribute

Tags: perl, authentication, active-directory, ldap

How to do a Perl LDAP search/authentication for user being an attribute in access group or it's subgroups?

All users (UIDs) are in:

```
ou=Users,o=company,c=com
```

Access group is:

```
cn=Site Full Access,ou=Access,o=company,c=com
```

Access group has users and subgroups as attributes like:

```
uniquemember | uid=usernameA,ou=Users,o=company,c=com
uniquemember | uid=usernameB,ou=Users,o=company,c=com
uniquemember | uid=usernameC,ou=Users,o=company,c=com
uniquemember | cn=Site Full Access Employees,ou=Access,o=company,c=com
```

(subgroup has its own uniquemember attributes)

Authentication script idea:

1. Bind user with his login/password (done).
2. If successful, create user's DN like `uid=$username,ou=Users,o=company,c=com` (done)
3. Iterate through attributes of `cn=Site Full Access,ou=Access,o=company,c=com` and compare them to user's DN
4. If encountered a group, search for user's DN inside this group too

I am using Net::LDAP, but there is not much code to show as what works is quite standard. This is the listing of uniquemember attributes:

```
my $mesg = $ldap->bind ($user_dn, password=>"$pass");
$mesg->code && return undef;

$mesg = $ldap->search(base=>$ldap_access_full, filter=>"(objectclass=*)");
$mesg->code && return undef;

my @entries = $mesg->entries;
my $entry;
foreach $entry ( @entries ) 
{
   if ($entry->exists('uniquemember'))
   {
      my $ref = $entr->get_value('uniquemember', asref=>1);
      for my $uid (@$ref)
      {
     print $uid . "<br/>";
      }
   }
}
```

This gives me an array of user DNs but also groups that will have to be listed and compared in some recursive function.

How do I approach this? Perhaps there is another way to check both password and access group, with user still being an attribute of access group or it's subgroups? I can't do any LDAP modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This called nested groups. For AD here is one solution: [How to retrieve all Groups from LDAP with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572644/how-to-retrieve-all-groups-from-ldap-with-perl)

One solution is to ignore groups, only allow direct user objects.

If you need to process sub groups you should retrieve the entry and check it is a group or people. In case you need to check this in many levels (sub groups of sub groups of..) then you needs to do the check recursivly.

For one level of nested groups. It is half complete and not tested but you got the idea.

Of course use subroutines, but I did not used for easier understanding (and lack of time)

```
$mesg = $ldap->search(base=>$ldap_access_full, filter=>"(objectclass=*)",attrs => [qw(uniquemember)]);
$mesg->code && die $mesg->code;

my @entries = $mesg->entries;
my $entry;

foreach $entry ( @entries ) {
    my @uniquemembers = $entr->get_value('uniquemember');
    foreach my $uniquemember (@uniquemembers){
        #get entry
        $mesg = $ldap->search(base=>$uniquemember, filter=>"(objectclass=*)", attrs => [qw(objectclass uid uniquemember)], scope => 'base');
        $mesg->code && die $mesg->code;
        #if is a group or user?
        my $uniquemember_entry = ($mesg->entries)[0];
        my @objectclasses = $uniquemember_entry->get_value('objectclass');

        my $uid = $uniquemember_entry->get_value('uid');
        if (grep {/user/i} @objectclasses || defined $uid){
            print "$uniquemember has uid: $uid\n";

        } elsif (grep {/group/i} @objectclasses){
            print "it is a group: $uniquemember\n";
            #get its members
            my @nested_group_uniquemembers = $uniquemember_entry->get_value('uniquemember');    
            #get entries
            foreach my $nested_group_uniquemember (@nested_group_uniquemembers){
                $mesg = $ldap->search(base=>$nested_group_uniquemember, filter=>"(objectclass=*)", attrs => [qw(objectclass uid uniquemember)], scope => 'base');
                $mesg->code && die $mesg->code;         
            }
            #check it is an user or group...
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is actually very similar to what I did in the end, but made me realize some minor performance mistakes I've made. Also, I'm using `if ($uniquemember =~ /^cn=/)` to check if it is a group. It might be a little faster than opening each uniquemember with ldap->search.

Comment: It could work, but what if somebody creates a person object like cn=john, doe?